# How to decrease and increase value in checkbox in reactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class App extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            total: 0,
            groupSelected:false
        };
    }
}
```

I have checkbox:

```
{check1 && size(check1) ? (
    map(check1, (ind, i) => {
        return (
            <AvCheckbox
                key={i}
                value={ind.id}
                onClick={() => this.setState({ groupSelected: !groupSelected })
                onChange={(e) => {this.add(e.target.value, ind.size)}}
            />
        )
    )

    add(value, size) {
        const { groupSelected } = this.state;

        if (groupSelected === true) {
          const total = this.state.total - parseInt(size);
    
          this.setState({
              total,
          });
        
        } else {
          const total = this.state.total + parseInt(size);

          this.setState({
            total,
        });
    }
}
```

This is what I have written, if a user clicks on a checkbox, a value will be increased and if he clicks another box value will decreased.

I want to increase and decrease the total according to checkbox.  Please help.

Comment: Your code could use a decent DRY pass. Can you clarify what you mean by clicking one checkbox increments and clicking another decrements. Your code snippet also appears to be incomplete. What are you mapping? Can you also include your `AvCheckbox` component code.

Answer (score 0):

Consider updating your state using the following:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
       return {total: prevState.total + parseInt(size)}
    })
```